# Assigning variables in loop Python

Tags: python, for-loop, dynamic-variables

I have this piece of:

```
As, Bs, Cs, Ds, Es = ([] for i in range(5))
for line in infile:
   line = line.rstrip()
    a, b, c, d, e = line.split('\t')
    As += [a]
    Bs += [b]
    Cs += [c]
    Ds += [d]
    Es += [e]
```

Since I have many more than just 5, I want to do this with a loop that takes up less lines of code than writing all of it out. Something like:

```
As, Bs, Cs, Ds, Es = ([] for i in range(5))
dynamic_variable_list = [As, Bs, Cs, Ds, Es]
    for line in infile:
        line = line.rstrip()
        for i in range(len(line.split('\t'))):
            dynamic_variable_list[i] += line.split('\t')[i]
```

Which in my case stores individual characters in the list, whereas:

```
dynamic_variable_list[i] += line.split('\t')
```

Stores all the tab delimited entries into each of the variables of `dynamic_variable_list`. What I need is to store all of the tab delimited entries in separate variables as the top example shows.

Answer (score 1):

```
dynamic_variable_list[i] += line.split('\t')[i]
```

Can be rewritten as

```
As += a
```

Rather than

```
As += [a]
```

Either surround in brackets like before, or use `append`. Or rather, split the list and then make it more clear.

```
dynamic_variable_list = [As, Bs, Cs, Ds, Es]
    for line in infile:
        columns = line.rstrip().split('\t')
        assert(len(columns)==len(dynamic_variable_list))
        for index, col in enumerate(columns):
            dynamic_variable_list[index].append(col)
```

Comment: {book = xlrd.open_workbook('file.xls') first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0) As, Bs, Cs, Ds, Es = ([] for i in range(5)) dyn_var_list = [As, Bs, Cs, Ds, Es] assert(len(first_sheet.row_values(0))==len(dyn_var_list)) for index, col in enumerate(first_sheet.row_values(0)): dyn_var_list[index].append(col)}
however, now I only get the first item in my dyn_var_list. Any suggestions here perhaps? I tried "first_sheet.col_values(0)" and "xrange(1, first_sheet.ncols):"